# Inserting multiple rows in database

Tags: java, database

I want to know which is a better approach of inserting multiple rows in database:

1. Using one query to do this or
2. `for( int x = 0; x < y.length; x++ ) { insertRowsIntoDatabase( valuesHere ); }`
3. Or you guys have another approach? Please share.

My data is consist about 8 columns and 50 rows.

Comment: Why don't you run some timed test cases and see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bulk insert`

save all values in a txt file and use.

```
BULK INSERT STUDENT
FROM ‘D:\STUDENTS_LIST.txt’
WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ‘,’, ROWTERMINATOR = ‘\n’ )
```

Comment: check this http://venzi.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/loading-data-fast-regular-insert-vs-bulk-insert/

Answer (score 3):

A better way would be to do a batch insert, instead of inserting rows 1 by 1.

```
for (String query : queries) {
    statement.addBatch(query);
}
statement.executeBatch();
```

Comment: Is this better than the one query?

Comment: Performance wise, not very sure(because internally, even the single query, *MAY* insert that many times, as the no. of rows), but readability wise, it is definitely better.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can write only one query to insert all values:

```
String query="insert into table1 (First,Last) values";
for(; ;)
{
    query=query+"('Fred','Smith'),";
}
 -----You can write your database insertion code here----
```

Or you can use addBatch()  and  executeBatch(); method also......

[Plz refer this link for read more about addBatch() Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-batch-processing.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Always use one query when you can. This has multiple advantages:

- Fewer connections to the DBMS, reducing the network access and other things done when you connect to the server (even if it's on the same computer as the program)
- Better optimization of the query. The DBMS is better than you at optimizing. Always. Doing multiple queries will hinder the optimization process of the DBMS, even with caching systems.

Anyway, 8 columns and 50 rows is very fast and easy to handle for any DBMS, but your data may grow later, so you want to use the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a single [Prepared Statement Batch](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/PreparedStatementBatchUpdate.htm), with multiple data sets as batch.

(Note: Not all JDBC drivers may support this and exactly follow the spec.)